# PHP 5.6 PCRE causes segfault on Magento 1.9.2.1 Community Edition

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

I'm experiencing a segfault during the cart update with a Magento 1.9.2.1 installation running on Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.6.29 (nginx 1.9 is front'ed as reverse proxy).

The problem happens when the user adds a second product in his/her cart and either it is a "configurable product" or it is a "simple product" but a configurable is already in the cart.

The problem is caused by PCRE going in a recursion|backtracking spree (not clear which one yet) and it is described in this article [Segmentation fult during rollback](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_segfault.html). The main difference is that I'm on Magento 1.9 and I'm not running via cli.

I already tried what has been suggested elsewhere and put these in php.ini (even if the Magento devdoc article raccomends not to):

```
[PCRE]
pcre.recursion_limit = 1000
pcre.backtrack_limit = 1000
```

The server has neither APC nor OPcache or Xcache.

`memory_limit` is already at 256 MB (another suggestion found).

I've yet to change ulimit (also a suggestion found) for the Apache users because it would require a reboot and this is a production server.

Tomorrow we'll try to disable additional modules one by one, but I'd also love some additional hint from the SE community.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I have what I think is much the same error on a very regular basis, and cannot find a solution. Unknown cause but might be the same? Magento 1.9.2.2 and PHP 5.6.30 on LiteSpeed (also happened on Apache). Would love to hear you found a solution!

Comment: I understood that it was a Magento bug with configurable products, fixed in EE but still not fixed today in CE. Manually applying the patch fixed the issue. Sorry for the lack of details but another dev took on the case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which patch do you refer to please?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details but another dev took on the case